# jQuery Accordion multiple sections open at once

Tags: jquery, accordion, sections

I'm trying to achieve multiple sections opened at once but when closing once section, the other sections are still open, like whats been done here http://jsfiddle.net/MZ4z9/

And i am trying to implement this within the jQuery accordion that i'm using here: http://jsfiddle.net/Lue6G/

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: like [THIS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Lue6G/5/) ????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `allPanels.slideUp();` with following line:

```
$(this).parent().next('dd').slideUp();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/WDzh9/)

Comment: You guys are awesome! ^_^ Thank you A.K!